# How to cut Last 3 elements in bash array and add them to an array

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, sed, ifs

ALright I currently am writting a script that will take a file with a delimiter of "~" and split it. However their is one item in the array the [5] element that needs to take the last 3 words of that element, cut them out and assign them to different values in the array, and then re adjust the element [5] to remove these items. I have tried sed, cut and other commands, but I am lost however. I am using bash for this script and below is the short form of my problem.

```
#!#!/bin/bash 
STR="FAILED~LOSS~Positive~MULTICOUNT~1~LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO DAD MAR  DE~5~489646.22~469646.22~5" 
IFS="~" read -ra STR_ARRAY <<< "$STR"

for x in "${STR_ARRAY[@]}"
    do
            echo "> [$x]"
    done
```

Current Print:

```
[0] = FAILED
[1] = LOSS
[2] = Positive
[3] = MULTICOUNT
[4] = 1
[5] = LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO DAD MAR DE
[6] = 5
[7] = 489646.22
[8] = 469646.22
[9] = 5
```

Wanted Print:

```
[0] = FAILED
[1] = LOSS
[2] = Positive
[3] = MULTICOUNT
[4] = 1
[5] = LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO 
[6] = DAD 
[7] = MAR 
[8] = DE
[9] = 5
[10] = 489646.22
[11] = 469646.22
[12] = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#!#!/bin/bash 
STR="FAILED~LOSS~Positive~MULTICOUNT~1~LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO DAD MAR  DE~5~489646.22~469646.22~5" 
IFS="~" read -ra STR_ARRAY <<< "$STR"
IFS=" " read -ra T <<< "${STR_ARRAY[5]}"
STR_ARRAY2=("${STR_ARRAY[@]:0:5}" "${T[*]:0:${#T[@]} - 3}" "${T[@]:(-3)}" "${STR_ARRAY[@]:6}")
printf '%s\n' "${STR_ARRAY2[@]}"
```

Output:

```
FAILED
LOSS
Positive
MULTICOUNT
1
LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO
DAD
MAR
DE
5
489646.22
469646.22
5
```

Comment: I just wrote exactly this and was about to paste it into my own answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

Tweak your STR to NEW_STR and use it with IFS=~ (small 2 line change)

```
$ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash
STR="FAILED~LOSS~Positive~MULTICOUNT~1~LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO DAD MAR  DE~5~489646.22~469646.22~5"

NEW_STR="$(echo $STR | sed "s/TWO DAD MAR DE/TWO~DAD~MAR~DE/")"

IFS="~" read -ra STR_ARRAY <<< "$NEW_STR"
for x in "${STR_ARRAY[@]}"
    do
            echo "> [$x]"
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./1.sh
> [FAILED]
> [LOSS]
> [Positive]
> [MULTICOUNT]
> [1]
> [LOSS SUMMARY - Log: One vs TWO]
> [DAD]
> [MAR]
> [DE]
> [5]
> [489646.22]
> [469646.22]
> [5]
```